# Python - How to sort a dictionary based on its value as well it key

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary as :-

```
{
 (1, 1): 16,
 (1, 2): 16,
 (1, 3): 16,
 (1, 4): 16,
 (2, 1): 24,
 (2, 2): 24,
 (2, 3): 24,
 (2, 4): 24   }
```

...i want it to be ordered as per tuple key's second field as well as dictionary's value field... so result dictionary should be :-

```
{
 (2, 1): 24,
 (2, 2): 24,
 (2, 3): 24,
 (2, 4): 24, 
 (1, 1): 16,
 (1, 2): 16,
 (1, 3): 16,
 (1, 4): 16 
}
```

... i tried sorting it with value alone but it messes the keys tuple order.... yes so i assigned it to a list afterwards by doing ...

```
list = sorted(unsorted_dict, key = unsorted_dict.__getitem__, reverse=True)....
```

Sorry to say but answer address my situation partially ...

i dont want to consider first value for sorting..lets say i had initial data ....

```
{
 (5, 1): 16,
 (6, 2): 16,
 (7, 3): 16,
 (8, 4): 16,
 (4, 1): 24,
 (3, 2): 24,
 (2, 3): 24,
 (1, 4): 24   }
```

and i wanted output ...

```
{
     (4, 1): 24,
     (3, 2): 24,
     (2, 3): 24,
     (1, 4): 24,     
     (5, 1): 16,
     (6, 2): 16,
     (7, 3): 16,
     (8, 4): 16        }
```

....as i said i want to consider tuples **second** value for sorting and not consider at all first value for sorting...Also it would be a great help if someone can tell ..how do i extract the tuples from this sorted dictionary to a list like ..

(4, 1),(3, 2),(2, 3),(1, 4),(5, 1),(6, 2),(7, 3),(8, 4)

**EDIT:** so the comment helped to get what i wanted ...thanks a lot ...

```
list_sorted = sorted(unsorted_dict.items(),key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0][1])) 
for val in list_sorted: 
   final_list.append(val[0])
```

**corrected the key,value pairs** thanks @Padraic Cunningham for pointing it out

Comment: But dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: I can drop the value afterwards and just get the list of tuples.. so basically value helps me in ordering (i use it like a priority) ...what i am interested in is the list of tuples and their order according to the priority assigned to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dicts` have no order, you can sort the items:

```
d={
 (1, 1): 16,
 (1, 2): 16,
 (1, 3): 16,
 (1, 4): 16,
 (2, 1): 24,
 (2, 2): 24,
 (2, 3): 24,
 (2, 4): 24   }

from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0])))
[((2, 1), 24),
 ((2, 2), 24),
 ((2, 3), 24),
 ((2, 4), 24),
 ((1, 1), 16),
 ((1, 2), 16),
 ((1, 3), 16),
 ((1, 4), 16)]
```

And if you really want a dict with the items in order you can create a [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the sorted items:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0])))
OrderedDict([((2, 1), 24), ((2, 2), 24), ((2, 3), 24), ((2, 4), 24), ((1, 1), 16), ((1, 2), 16), ((1, 3), 16), ((1, 4), 16)])
```

Our primary sort key is each value, sorting from high to low by negating each value with a `-`, then we break ties with the key/tuple sorting from low to high.

Break ties by second  element in tuple:

```
pp(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0][1])))
```

Your edited output now has different keys with different values so not sure how sort can do that.

Comment: @Lafada. I have given up trying to figure out downvotes!

Comment: the second was me :D i think the down voter doesn't  seen your edit! so Pluse 1 ;)

Comment: OK so -x[1] here represents values in the dict. and..x[0] .. one of field of tuple ..but how which tuple fields it considers for sorting 1st or 2nd ..i am not able to figure out...

Comment: @user1107108, `x[0]`  **is** the tuple, not one field.

Comment: yes ...so on what basis its sorting those tuples..as i have two values in it..and i want sorting to be done based on 2nd value..sorry if have have used wrong terminology anywhere.. very new to python

Comment: lowest to highest. compare 1st digits, if they are the same compare second digits

Comment: ok let me try this...my initial question does mention about second field ..but may be i dint emphised it much earlier

Comment: The sort is sorting by the second field but to also sort ties based on the values in the tuples you need a secondary key. If you want to sort by a particular element in the tuple you simply index. Also your output has changed the key value pairings in your dict in your edited expected output