# sort a list according to keys and for elements with same keys as per values in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

I started learning python recently. I am trying to sort a list of lists similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762489/python-how-to-sort-a-dictionary-based-on-its-value-as-well-it-key). However, I'm not able to find the correct method to do so please help.

Consider the list `[[1,4], [3,3], [3,2] ,[1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [1,5]]`

now, using

```
def keyFunc(j):
        return j[0]

job = sorted(job, key=keyFunc, reverse=True)
```

I got it down to `[[all 3s], [all 2s], [all 1s]]`

However, now I want to further sort it so that the lists with common keys are in the order of descending values of their keys.

i.e. [[3,3], [3,2], [2,3], [1,5], [1,4], [1,3], [1,2]]

How does one do that in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python sort list of lists / ascending and then decending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666748/python-sort-list-of-lists-ascending-and-then-decending)

Comment: -- but keep in mind that question sorts the second item ascending. To sort descending, just remove that `-` in the lambda key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use a wrong key function when **not** using a key function already does what you want?

```
>>> sorted(job, reverse=True)
[[3, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [1, 5], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
```

Or since you're assigning back to `job` anyway, you might want to do `job.sort(reverse=True)` instead of creating a new list.

Comment: I thought I was supposed to pass in a key. See, that's what. I am entirely a noob here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just negate the sorting keys to sort descending twice:

```
>>> lst = [[1,4], [3,3], [3,2] ,[1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [1,5]]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (-x[0], -x[1]))
[[3, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [1, 5], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
```

`(-x[0], -x[1])` will first sort by the first item, then if any ties occur sort on the second item, both in descending manner. We can make it descending by negating with the minus `-` sign.

But as suggested by [@Heap Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365384/sort-a-list-according-to-keys-and-for-elements-with-same-keys-as-per-values-in-p/61365638#61365638), we don't need to do this because we can just pass `reverse=True`, and `sorted()` will naturally sort by the first item then the second in descending order. No need for a sorting key.

You can test this by running the following:

```
>>> sorted(lst, reverse=True)
[[3, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [1, 5], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]), reverse=True)
[[3, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [1, 5], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
```

Which both give the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the keyFunc to be like

```
def keyFunc(j):
    return j[0]*10+j[1]
```

or

```
ls = [[3, 3], [3, 2], [2, 3], [1, 5], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
sorted(ls, key=lambda x: x[0]*10+x[1], reverse=True)
```

That will sort both of the numbers as you described.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But you see, the thing is, this code will work only for this particular question (Granted that's what I wanted, so I am at fault), but what if the key is a string and the value is an integer? Will this code still work?

Comment: A string like '3'? or with chars?

Comment: How would you like to sort such a case?

Comment: sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0] if type(x[0]) == int else sum([ord(y) for y in x[0]]) *10+ x[1] if type(x[0]) == int else sum([ord(y) for y in x[0]]), reverse=True) that will make the job